# How to integrate JS / CSS only on specified Pages / custom content types

Tags: javascript, theming

I would like embed my module JS / CSS files only in specified cases.
Like on a /url/ or if a custom content type is rendered?

Comment: Short suggestion - don't. Use classes to detect if specific script or rule should apply.

Comment: Oh think you got my wrong. It is not about the detection. I wont to reduce the amount of JS / CSS request. Respectively reduce the size of files, if aggregation is activated.

Comment: But by that you will increase amount of requests, not decrease it. With constant set of CSS / JS, user will obtain them once, and his browser will use locally cached version. With dynamically changing sets, it will be harder. And it will ruin any aggregation you may have (Drupal's built in one, or these added by modules).

Answer (score 2):

The concept given by Molot is good. Because url can be changed any time.

Still you can add the css and js file using hook_preprocess_page or yourtheme_preprocess_node in your template.php of active theme.

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
// Add JS & CSS by node type
if( $vars['type'] == "your-node-type") {
drupal_add_js( /* parameters */ );
drupal_add_css( /* parameters */ );
}
```

where **yourtheme** need to be replaced by the name of the your active theme.
Please clear cache for changes to reflect.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: would this be also possible inside a .module-file?

Comment: yes just use the name of your module as we are using in place of`yourtheme` variable

Comment: no reaction, even if i try to dump something.. mymodule_preprocess_node is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)(if you're changing the form for the content type) and put it in your theme's template file to target specific node types.

You can also target [theming](https://www.drupal.org/node/17565)(from the official documentation) for certain node types by adding templates for them.

As a rule, you should avoid injecting JS/CSS into pages.

Lastly, I would use the theme's CSS or SASS files to add your CSS for caching and aggregating purposes.

Clear your Drupal and browser caches, for the changes to take effect.

Comment: hook_form_alter does not allow you to target specific node types. It's for altering forms, as the name suggests.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong But doesn't that mean alter form for specific node type? Like for example: adding an Article content type. If I want to alter the form to look a certain way or style it differently because I am exposing that content type to the Anonymous user. Then I would use hook_form_alter.

Comment: Yeah, but he asked about rendering content types, not their forms.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong Thanks, I will add that as a comment.